# How to store the old data of a table before update query

Tags: php, mysql

How can I store the old value of the selected ID in a table before update query? I have this code for my insert query and update query . I want to save the old value of the selected ID before my UPDATE query.

```
        <form method="post" id="reg-form" action="user_save">
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                  <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="margin-right:-10px">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                  <th>RECRUITER</th>
  </tr>
                    </thead>
<?php
                    include('../dist/includes/dbcon.php');
                    $bdo=$_SESSION['name'];
                    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM accounts_at ")or die(mysqli_error());

                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                  $id=$row['id'];
                    $rec=$row['rec'];
<tr>
                   <td><?php echo $rec;?></td>
<td>
                              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="click" href="user_edit.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit text-blue"></i></a>
                                 </td>
```

And this is my user_update query .

```
    <?php session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['id'])):
    header('Location:../index');
endif;
include('../dist/includes/dbcon.php');
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id']);
$rec= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['rec']);

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE accounts_at set rec='$rec' where id='$id'")or 
die(mysqli_error());

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully updated account 
details!');</script>";
echo "<script>document.location='update_acc'</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Wow, that's an ugly way to do. First of all, don't mix PHP in your HTML. Limit it at the minimum like echo, loop etc. You can do that by calling function for example. Take a look to MVC arcitecture. Secondly, use function to fractionate your code. By doing that you could easilly call a function to stored the ID before running a query.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: A simple version system consists of a secondary table you can save serialized data into, like dump out the record in JSON format.

Comment: Okay sir. So how Can I save the data of selected ID before updating the table?

Answer (score 0):

it is dependent on how you want to save this data ?
you can save it in file as you can use fopen() and write it first 
or send it to your self via mail()

```
$save_method = //method you want to save data
if($save_method){//code to update data}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering. I want to save this to my database on history column . I need some suggestion on how to manage the query's . Because I want to save the current data on a selected ID if the user CLICKS the EDIT ICON BUTTON it automatically INSERT INTO the HISTORY table.

Comment: Ok so your problem is "how to run a php function by a javascript event". You need to take a look to AJAX.

Comment: Javascript event? Hmm it is possible to made this on PHP?